# Regular Expression intellij-idea replace

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and I would please like some help with a Regular Expression to get some results like this:

```
    patient.setIdentificationDate(new Date()); -> {IdentificationDate} and {new Date()}
    patient.setIdentificationNumber(153698); -> {IdentificationNumber} and {153698}
    patient.setIdentificationSeries("33 02"); -> {IdentificationSeries} and {"33 02"}
```

p.s. thanks alot

Comment: The fact that you are using Intellij adds absolutely nothing to the question. Wit that code, you are using Java, or maybe Javascript, and that is the tags that you must add to your question.

Comment: Actually it does, since regular expressions in intellij search/replace dialog are not the same as regular expressions in awk, javascript, or whatever.

Comment: seems like a reasonable enough question to me - could be a bit clearer though: Is he looking to generate/replace/ or just find lines like these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are doing `Replace in path` to modify your source code via a regular expression?

If that is the case, you can open up `Replace in path` dialog (ctrl-shift-r), tick *Regular Expression* and enter the following:

Text to find: `patient.set([A-Za-z]*)\((.*)(\);)`

Replace with: `{$1} and {$2}`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this regex pattern replace will work

```
patient.set([^(]*)\((.*)\);
```

replace with

```
{$1} and {$2}
```

[image]